# How to rename a file in linux by removing certain characters from the file name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I rename a file in linux to strip out certain characters from the file name?

For example,

My123File.txt to be renamed to My123.txt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're okay with just wildcards (not full regexes), then you might try something like

```
f='My123File.txt'
mv $f ${f/File/}
```

This type of shell expansion is documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

If you really need regexes, try

```
f='My123File.txt'
mv $f $(echo $f | sed -e 's/File//')
```

Answer (score 5):

User rename, here's a test:

```
$ touch My123File.txt
$ rename 's/File//' My123File.txt
```

See `man rename`. `rename` supports regexps, so you can do for example this - execute somewhere safe, e.g. /tmp or so:

```
cd /tmp
rm *.txt
touch My123File.txt My456File.txt
ls *.txt
rename 's/([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)(\w+)/$3-999-$2-$1/' *.txt
ls *.txt
```

yields this:

```
My123File.txt  My456File.txt
File-999-123-My.txt  File-999-456-My.txt
```

Comment: I think you mean `rename File '' My123File.txt` for that second line.

Comment: rename File '' My123File.txt   works but I want to be able to use regular expressions.

Comment: @jjlin Actually, I meant what I wrote - try it yourself to see what it will do. @SS This is a regexp, see `man rename`. See my edit for an example.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. You're right about Debian `rename`. The CentOS `rename` doesn't have regex capability, though.

Comment: @jjlin Ah, OK, didn't know that. That's a shame :( Well, +1 for Debian / Ubuntu! ;)

Answer (score 1):

With mmv, it's a single command a lot simpler. It also has support for translations such as lowercasing a positional parameter.

```
mmv '*File.txt' '#1.txt'
```